# Work around multiple inheritance

Tags: inheritance, swift

I basically have two view controllers. Both of them will work with one other controller/manager. I want this manager to be exactly the same for both controllers. So both controllers should have a reference to the same manager/controller.  There is also a third class that uses the manager.

At first I thought I could just inherit the manager/controller to both view controllers. But Swift doesn't allow this. So, how exactly can I realise this idea?

All with all this is the deal:

I have these four classes:

FirstViewController (inherits UIViewController)

SecondViewController (Inherits UIVIewController)

EventController (inherits nothing - yet)

MapManager (Inherits nothing)

The firstviewcontroller, secondviewcontroller and MapManager need to use the functions/properties in the EventController.

What I have now:

First, SecondViewcontrollers and MapManager inherit from EventController which is of type UIViewController. Yet, in the map manager class the properties of the EventController are not working properly (e.g: filled arrays are empty)

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 or more `UIViewController` (or similar) having common behavior, you can create a base class `BaseViewController`, inherited from `UIViewController`, and then make your specialized view controllers inherit from it

```
        UIViewController
               |
       BaseViewController
         |           | 
ViewController1 ViewController2
```

If there's another class involved in the equation, this solution doesn't work. Swift, like many modern languages, support single inheritance only.

For simplicity let's call the additional class "manager". I see 3 alternate solutions ways:

1. create an instance of the manager in the base view controller (as a property), and expose its interface via wrapper methods (i.e. create a protocol for the manager, implement it in the base view controller, the implementation simply forwards the requests to the manager instance)
2. create an instance of the manager in the base view controller (as a property), and make it accessible to subclasses
3. get rid of the manager class and merge its code into the base view controller

This list is of course non exhaustive. The argument is too broad to give a targeted advice, and there's no solution that can work in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention there is another class (of the type NSObject) which uses the manager (in your example the baseviewcontroller). How to perform such a hierarchy?

Comment: That drastically changes things... updated the answer with some advices, I can't be more specific because a good solution requires much more knowledge of the existing code and its architecture.